# Подсчет скорости передвижения

Tags: математика, геометрия

Есть такой код:

```
float speedx = mem.ReadFloat(add+0x44);
float speedy = mem.ReadFloat(add+0x48);

float normal_speedy = speedy*20;
float normal_speedx = speedx*20;

float current = normal_speedx + normal_speedy; // это чисто мое, не работает
```

В переменную normal_speedy - записывается скорость движения персонажа по оси Y.
В переменную normal_speedx - записывается скорость движения персонажа по оси X.

Нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы мы могли знать.. Постоянную, что ли, скорость. Что я подразумеваю под "постоянной" - если двигаться лишь по оси X - скорость показывается нормально, НО! Стоит свернуть влево или вправо (уже чуть-чуть задевать Y) - так уже скорость может увеличиваться в зависимости от того, куда я свернул. Если влево (к примеру) - скорость может увеличиваться, вправо - уменьшаться. P.S - ВСЕ ЭТО МЕСИВО ПРОИСХОДИТ В ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ `current`.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы независимо от того, как персонаж движется, скорость должна быть одинаковой.

Возможно, нужно посчитать среднее между X и Y..

Comment: `current` надо вычислять по теореме Пифагора: `float current = sqrt(normal_speedx * normal_speedx + normal_speedy * normal_speedy)`. Функция `sqrt` — это взятие квадратного корня. В каждом языке она вызывается немного по-разному, так что уточняйте конкретный способ на месте.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Немного физики:
Скорости, которые вы называете normal_speedx и normal_speedy, являются проекциями вектора скорости на оси X и Y соответственно. "Постоянная, что ли,
скорость" называется модулем скорости, иначе длиной вектора скорости.

Считается модуль скорости при известных проекциях с помощью теоремы Пифагора:
absoluteSpeed2D = √(speedX² + speedY²)
absoluteSpeed3D = √(speedX² + speedY² + speedZ²)

На C#, т.к. он есть в метках:

```
double speedX, speedY, speedZ;

double absoluteSpeed2D = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(speedX, 2) + Math.Pow(speedY, 2));
double absoluteSpeed3D = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(speedX, 2) + Math.Pow(speedY, 2) + Math.Pow(speedZ, 2));
```

А вообще, стыдно такие вещи не знать. Класс седьмой, самое начало геометрии.